# Utilizing the vNIC of a VM

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, vpn, network-adapter, vmware-fusion

So, I have a Mac, on which I have virtualized a Windows VM using VMware Fusion. There is a specific VPN application which I have to use, that is only available on Windows. For this, I have to use my Windows VM which is not very comfortable. I wanted to know if there was a way to route my traffic through the VPN adapter in the Windows VM therefore, all the traffic that is originating from the Mac (base OS) also passes through the VPN tunnel that the Windows VM builds.

(Please do not suggest any other alternatives like use OpenVPN etc. as I would like to specifically try to route the traffic through my Windows VM)

Comment: I re-tagged macOS rather than networking, as it may require more specialist knowledge.